# How do I mount a remote Linux folder in Windows through SSH?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I'm a blind student currently in a system admin/shell programming class. Although ssh works fine for executing commands like ls, pwd, etc editors do not work well with my screen reader and an ssh session. I was wondering if it is possible to mount a Linux folder over ssh so it appears as a windows drive? This way I could edit any files I needed to with accessible software and not have to constantly use SCP to send files back and fourth.

Comment: what distribution of linux are you running? Do you have root access or some other means to install software on the linux box?

Comment: A small Linux VM with shared folder would do (at least ubuntu 10.04 had out of the box support for sshfs) - if you have some ram/cpu spare.

Comment: Duplicate of [Map remote drive in Windows over SSH](http://superuser.com/questions/291786/map-ssh-drive-in-windows) on SU and [Open source tool to map SFTP connections as a Windows drive](http://serverfault.com/questions/6919/is-there-an-open-source-tool-to-map-sftp-connections-as-a-windows-mapped-drive) on SF.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Back in 2002, Novell developed some software called [NetDrive](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/999.html) that can map a WebDAV, FTP, SFTP, etc. share to a windows drive letter. It is now abandonware, so it's no longer maintained (and not available on the Novell website), but it's free to use. I found quite a few available to download by searching for "netdrive.exe" I actually downloaded a few and compared their md5sums to make sure that I was getting a common (and hopefully safe) version.

**Update 10 Nov 2017**
[SFTPNetDrive](https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/drive/) is the current project from the original netdrive project. And they made it free for personal use:

> We Made SFTP Net Drive FREE for Personal Use

They have paid options as well on the website.

Comment: Second :(. Anyway, the explorer integration worths mentioning.

Comment: Netdrive 4.1 doesn't seem to handle sftp

Comment: Is this compatible with Windows 10?

Comment: Thank you for this. I was able to install in windows 10.

Comment: [SFTP Drive](https://www.nsoftware.com/sftp/drive/) works in Windows 11.

Answer (score 43):

[Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/) looks like a FUSE and sshfs implementation for Windows. If it works as expected and advertised, it would do exactly what you are looking for.

(Link updated and working 2015-10-15)

Comment: Good find! Sounds like a real treat. Shame that the SSHFS component isn't Free like the rest of the package; it would really simplify things at work. :-)

Comment: Currently SSHFS doesn't work on x64.

Comment: I'd just wish dokan sshfs would talk to pageant to get the private key... otherwise it seems to work

Comment: Just installed the latest DOkan requirements as of today, and it keeps crashing when I attempt to connect using an OpenSSH key pair.

Comment: @ Sorin Sbarnea: Was true, but is not true anymore.

Comment: @DanDascalescu same here.. any solution?

Comment: does not work on windows 7 64bit. keeps crashing all the time. anyone found some workaround ?

Comment: Dokan is working for me without problems using win8/64 with a login/password! I followed these 2 simple steps: http://gusclass.com/blog/2012/12/27/remote-mounting-ssh-filesystems-from-windows-8/

Comment: I used win-sshfs and it works really good - with one major downside. Timestamps are not updated. Most likely all implementations that use Dokan library will have similar problem.

Comment: Link is dead. https://code.google.com/p/dokan/ is supposedly an archive, but I can't verify.

Comment: Heres a great new writeup I found on steps to install and use Win-SSHFS and DOKANY (DOKAN): https://igikorn.com/sshfs-windows-10/

Comment: @GabrielStaples link seems dead today.

Comment: Yeah that's too bad. I don't know what to do about it. :( Wayback machine (https://archive.org/web/) doesn't seem to have that page archived either. I can say though that [SFTP Net Drive](https://www.nsoftware.com/netdrive/sftp/), as linked to in the main answer by Sunny Milenov, does work really well, and is free (no cost, not open source) for personal use. It works great.

Answer (score 29):

The best an easiest solution I found is https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win, connected servers shows up as a fully functioning network drives. This is not a 'Dokany' or 'dokan' based solution which from experiance seems more stable and performant, also see [WinFsp Performance Testing](https://github.com/billziss-gh/winfsp/wiki/WinFsp-Performance-Testing).

[image: mount ssh on windows]

*Please note previously this answer stated, https://github.com/Foreveryone-cz/win-sshfs and before that http://www.swish-sftp.org/ but I no longer use any of them, first one stopped working second one created drives not fully supported in all programs.*

Comment: Great tool :) but I'd like to connect it using a drive letter... i.e. I'd like to connect `sftp://server.com/dir/subdir` as `Z:\subdir` - it doesn't work :(

Comment: @endolith it's read and write; you probably only have read permissions.

Comment: Most application don't support the swish paths (not UNC?). So it does not help here.

Comment: And it doesnt support ssh key files. :-(

Comment: @Mirko It does support ssh agent (like Pageant) where you can add your ssh keys. Works great!

Comment: @Christian correct I had the same issue, this is why I use win-sshfs which does not have this limitation.

Answer (score 14):

Another, more Windows-y option (for $39) is http://www.expandrive.com/sftpdrive

Comment: Works for me, albeit a bit slowly.

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: Since longer, don't know the exact date. Just that it didn't work error free on x64 until about something like half a year ago. The better question is how do you create an RSA key on windows, but there, gitbash @ google-code to the rescue.

Comment: @Quandary: Great. Last time I tried it it didn't do all that.

Comment: This looks cool. Unfortunately, the current version (2) doesn't work on Windows 8. The installer notified me that version 3 will support Windows 8.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at CIFS (http://www.samba.org/cifs/). It is a virtual file system you can run on your linux machine that will allow you to mount folders on your linux machine in windows using SMB.

CIFS on linux information can be found here: http://linux-cifs.samba.org/

Comment: Samba is HORRIBLE to use over a slow/high-latency (pretty much anything that's not your LAN) connection.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Heavy agreed with you,the read file performance of samba in virtual machine is too bad.

Answer (score 4):

You need to mount a remote share on your windows machine. This is what [Samba/smb](http://us3.samba.org/samba/) is for.

What you'll be doing is turning your Linux box into an SMB server, which lets it share files in a way that plays nice with Windows.

If you're not on the same network, you'll need to tunnel this through your SSH connection which may not be worth the effort.

Comment: SSH tunnels with PuTTy really aren't that bad.  It'll automatically initiate the tunnel when you connect.  If you set it to run on startup and use private-key login with no passphrase (warning, not secure!!!), you'll immediately be ready to go.

Comment: I'd rather not set up samba since it's an extra step the rest of the class won't use. Also I trust SSH more then Samba and the campus network isn't what I'd call secure considering how many students are on it with personal computers running god knows what.

Comment: Jared: if you went with samba, you'd have to tunnel it through SSH anyway--so it'd be equally safe as ssh. If you really want an easy drag-drop method, then WinSCP is nice, as suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

check out Dokan

https://dokan-dev.github.io/

it's iffy, but it works, and it's free

Comment: Site does not exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can mount a Linux folder as a network drive under windows having only access to ssh. I can suggest you to use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) that allows you to transfer file through ssh and it's free.

EDIT: well, sorry. Vinko posted before me and now i've learned a new thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the free [NetDrive](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/999.html) software from Novell can access SFTP file servers.

Answer (score 0):

Second David's answer below: I needed to mount a network drive automatically when users logged in.  Dokan SSHFS is a nice tool, but wasn't reliable enough in this case.  The copy of Netdrive I found didn't support SSHFS or sftp - not sure if a more recent one does.

The solution I'm trialling now involves adding a virtual network adapter (with file sharing disabled), using plink to open a tunnel via the new adapter to the remote machine running SAMBA, and mounting the network drive against the new adapter.  There's another useful tutorial here http://www.blisstonia.com/eolson/notes/smboverssh.php.

The tunnel and network drive can be set up with a login script, so a few seconds after login users can use the mapped drive without needing to take any action.