# hg archive to Remote Directory

Tags: mercurial, ssh, dvcs, archive

Is there any way to archive a Mercurial repository to a remote directory over SSH?  For example, it would be nice if one could do the following:

```
hg archive ssh://user@example.com/path/to/archive
```

However, that does not appear to work. It instead creates a directory called `ssh:` in the current directory.

I made the following quick-and-dirty script that emulates the desired behavior by creating a temporary ZIP archive, copying it over SSH, and unzipping the destination directory. However, I would like to know if there is a better way.

```
if [[ $# != 1 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 [user@]hostname:remote_dir"
  exit
fi

arg=$1

arg=${arg%/} # remove trailing slash
host=${arg%%:*}
remote_dir=${arg##*:}
# zip named to match lowest directory in $remote_dir
zip=${remote_dir##*/}.zip 

# root of archive will match zip name
hg archive -t zip $zip  
# make $remote_dir if it doesn't exist
ssh $host mkdir --parents $remote_dir
# copy zip over ssh into destination
scp $zip $host:$remote_dir  
# unzip into containing directory (will prompt for overwrite)
ssh $host unzip $remote_dir/$zip -d $remote_dir/..
# clean up zips
ssh $host rm $remote_dir/$zip 
rm $zip
```

**Edit**: `clone`-and-`push` would be ideal, but unfortunately the remote server does not have Mercurial installed.

Comment: @Brett Daniel: I was going to post the answer that Paul Nathan posted.  Wouldn't simply a *"hg push ssh://user@example.com/hg/"* work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, this is not possible -- we always assume that there is a functioning Mercurial installation on the remote host.

I definitely agree with you that this functionality would be nice, but I think it would have to be made in an extension. Mercurial is not a general SCP/FTP/rsync file-copying program, so don't expect to see this functionality in the core.

This reminds me... perhaps you can built on the [FTP extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FTPExtension) to make it do what you want. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer. It's good to hear straight from a Mercurial developer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply having a clone on the remote and doing `hg push` to archive?

Comment: That would be ideal, but unfortunately the remote host does not have Mercurial installed.

Comment: @Brett: is it possible to locally install hg? I have done that in several places before.

Comment: That would work, but I am still curious if there is a way to archive remotely and if not, why?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a ssh tunnel to mount a remote directory on your local machine and then just do standard `hg clone` and `hg push` operations 'locally' (as far as HG knows) but where they actually write to a filesystem which is on the remote computer?

It looks like there are several stackoverflow questions about doing this:

- [How do I mount a remote Linux folder in Windows through SSH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443732/how-do-i-mount-a-remote-linux-folder-in-windows-through-ssh)
- [Map SSH drive in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186968/map-ssh-drive-in-windows)
- [How can I mount a remote directory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637372/how-can-i-mount-a-remote-directory-on-my-computer)

Answer (score 1):

I am often in a similar situation.  The way I get around it is with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

1. `sshfs me@somewhere-else:path/to/repo local/path/to/somewhere-else`
2. `hg archive local/path/to/somewhere-else`
3. `fusermount -r somewhere-else`

The only disadvantage is sshfs is slower than nfs, samba or rsync.  Generally I don't notice as I only rarely need to do anything in the remote file-system.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply execute hg on the remote host:

```
ssh user@example.com "cd /path/to/repo; hg archive -r 123 /path/to/archive"
```