# Remote python libraries with Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext2, vagrant, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am working with a virtual machine through [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), and would like my [ST3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)  editor to recognize the `python` libraries that are installed in the virtual machine (not in my host). With this, I could use the ST3 plugins like autocompletion or linters, according to the libraries I'm actually using in the virtual machine, and not those installed in my computer (host).

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313131/change-python-interpreter-sublime-text-2) but I don't think it is the same problem we are facing here, because it's not a matter of interpreter I guess, but rather a problem of which path is used for looking for libraries. The problem would be the same if we consider virtual environments under the project root.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the directory of libraries with something like sshfs?

Comment: I didn't find necessary, because the vagrant tool allows to have synced folders with the host machine. The connection to the virtual machine is through `ssh` and softwares like `PyCharm` actually let the use of a remote interpreter for python (and its installed libraries). I was guessing on ST3 something simliar could exist.

Comment: I finally did something like you propose. I explained it in a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019120/define-remote-interpreter-on-remote-linux-machine-using-pydev-and-rse-server/27496846#27496846

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can, through some plugins. For instance, the [anaconda](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/wiki/Vagrant-Environments) plugin for sublime text can do this through a project file setting. I believe the same can be done for [REPLs](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) by pointing your project's `python_interpreter_path` to a remote interpreter through ssh, although I haven't tried this personally.