# Configuring Visual Studio Code for remote Python interpreter via SSH

Tags: python, configuration, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, ssh-tunnel

I have a Vagrant box with ArchLinux and Python which uses a virtual environment per project (by using a certain Python version). I wish to configure VSC for running/debugging these Python projects. I've mounted the directory containing my projects (with **sshfs**) so I don't have to worry about sync.

With PyCharm the configuration is only in its IDE. How can I configure it for VSC by using SSH? What are other plugins necessary to work with Python?

Thanks in advance.

PS1: PyCharm is a great tool but it takes much resources, near 1GB in RAM.

PS2: I've read [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) but it is not clear for me, one example is more useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post [Define remote interpreter on remote Linux machine using Pydev and RSE Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11019120/define-remote-interpreter-on-remote-linux-machine-using-pydev-and-rse-server) was really useful, it seems so obvious now. This is my workaround using my own system configuration:

**Step 1**: Mount your remote home folder.

```
$ sshfs -o password_stdin,transform_symlinks vagrant@localhost:/home/vagrant ~/Vagrant/archi02/Remote/ -p 2222 <<< "your_vagrant_password"
```

**Step 2**: Open your project folder with VSC.

```
~/Vagrant/archi02/Remote/Projects/Python_3_7_2/QuickPythonBook/
```

**Step 3**: Configure "*settings.json*" (from *WorkSpace Settings*) for your remote Python and linter.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "~/Vagrant/archi02/Remote/Projects/Python_3_7_2/QuickPythonBook/ve_qpb/bin/python3.7",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "pylint"
}
```

**Step 4**: Enjoy programming. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I wrote a new and improved answer to this question here: [vscode python remote interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320958/vscode-python-remote-interpreter/54789809#54789809)

Using the VScode terminal you can run the Python code on a remote machine over SSH with:

```
cat hello_world.py | ssh user@hostname python -
```

You can add this as as your VSCode build task with `${file}` pointing to the current file. If you need remote debugging in VScode you can read the following steps: code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging

Additionally, you could also create an `alias` or `function` in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file that makes executing files on a remote machine, potentially in a virtualenv, more convenient. For example, my `.zshrc` file contains the following function to execute Python files on my workstation in a remote virtualenv:

```
function remote-pytorch () {
    cat $1 | ssh user@hostname 'source ~/virtualenv/pytorch/bin/activate && python -'
}
```

This way, I can just run the following command to execute the script remotely:

```
remote-pytorch train_network.py
```

(note: the syntax for functions is slightly different in `.bashrc` files)