# Read/write data between matlab on local machine and remote Linux server

Tags: linux, matlab, remote-access, putty

I have been using PuTTY to jump into a remote Linux server (cluster) to use a software installed on it. The results from the software are then downloaded/transferred to my windows PC. I then update a matlab script (on my local machine) with these results and solve for new outputs which I then feed back into the cluster.

Basically what I am wanting to do is automate this process. Achieving the above process manually is simple, but what I am struggling with is how to get matlab to access the Linux server and read/write data back and fourth with my local machine. So I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on what tools/methods could achieve this. Ideally if all/most of this could be initiated within matlab then that would be preferred. However my experience with the Linux environment is quite limited so any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Just for clarity, I've summarised the steps I want to achieve below;

1. Jump into the Linux environment
2. Execute a sh file
3. Transfer the outputs to my local machine (this will be in the form of a text file)
4. Read the data into my matlab script and solve for new outputs
5. Jump back into the Linux environment and update the sh file with the outputs generated by matlab
6. Repeat above steps until a set condition is met.

Comment: Can matlab be installed into cluster? Is Linux machines and Windows PC on same network? If Linux cluster and Windows PC on same network then your work directory in cluster can be mounter on your PC over Samba protocol as network drive. There is one possible pitfall that if network is not reliable then running Matlab on _remote files_ can loose _connection_ with files. Other possibility to mount your cluster disk _resource_ to your PC over iSCSI protocol in this case remote disk _resource_ will look like local disk, but same pitfalls with unreliable network.

Comment: Third possibility is to mount your Windows PC shared directory to Linux cluster -- I guess that Sys Admin will be against such solution [it pollute his cluster domain].

Comment: Forth possible solution is to use special SSH software which will make your remote _disk resource_ appear on your machine as _network drive_. Same pitfalls at play - if network is not reliable then you may corrupt remote files (not complete write). [sshfs](http://makerlab.cs.hku.hk/index.php/en/mapping-network-drive-over-ssh-in-windows), [NetDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443732/how-do-i-mount-a-remote-linux-folder-in-windows-through-ssh).

Digital Ocean tutorial [sshfs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh).

Comment: **NOTE:** before modifying remote files do backup copy to stay safe if something goes wrong.